# iOS crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000

Tags: ios, crash, masonry-ios-osx

I have received some crashes via Crashlytics. It crashed 4 times in last month.
I use `Masonry` for autolayout and add constraint in `layoutSubviews`. You can see the crash trace below.

```
0   libsystem_platform.dylib    _platform_memmove + 284
1   Foundation  _NSBitSetResize.llvm.9545202549352731061 + 288
2   Foundation  NSBitSetAddIndex + 52
3   Foundation  NSISLinExpEnumerateVars + 88
4   Foundation  _row_setHead + 156
5   Foundation  -[NSISEngine tryAddingDirectly:] + 236
6   Foundation  -[NSISEngine _tryToAddConstraintWithMarkerEngineVar:row:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 156
7   Foundation  -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 684
8   Foundation  -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 252
9   Foundation  -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 188
10  UIKitCore   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 548
11  UIKitCore   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraintWithoutUpdatingConstraintsArray:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 36
12  UIKitCore   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) nsli_addConstraint:] + 84
13  ChopeDashboard  MASViewConstraint.m line 361  -[MASViewConstraint install] + 361
14  ChopeDashboard  MASConstraintMaker.m line 46  -[MASConstraintMaker install] + 46
15  ChopeDashboard  View+MASAdditions.m line 18  -[UIView(MASAdditions) mas_makeConstraints:] + 18
16  ChopeDashboard  CDResListHeaderView.m line 128  -[CDResListHeaderView layoutSubviews] + 128
17  UIKitCore   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2140
18  QuartzCore  -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 284
19  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 480
20  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 136
21  QuartzCore  CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 304
22  QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::commit() + 676
23  QuartzCore  CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 888
24  IOKit   IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 488
25  CoreFoundation  __CFMachPortPerform + 172
26  CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
27  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 444
28  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 2168
29  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
30  GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 104
31  UIKitCore   UIApplicationMain + 1936
32  ChopeDashboard  main.m line 14 main + 14
33  libdyld.dylib   start + 4
```

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: It’s an autolayout issue.

Comment: @matt I can't reproduce it. It's really hard to detect the code place.

Comment: 13  ChopeDashboard  MASViewConstraint.m line 361  -[MASViewConstraint install] + 361
14  ChopeDashboard  MASConstraintMaker.m line 46  -[MASConstraintMaker install] + 46 try to start your search from here, maybe there is some conflict?